# Runtime error for Release build app in XCode 4

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4

I'm having some issues with running a app in Release build in Xcode 4. I get a run-time error on a message send to a Category method:

```
[NSCFString JSONValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x923600
```

I guess the category for some reason is not found correctly. There is no warnings, and 
this only happens in Release builds. The JSON Category is located in a static lib, linked to the main app. The project configuration still contains the -all_load flag.

**EDIT:**

This is the offending code:

```
    NSString *rawJson = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ;
    NSDictionary *dataDic =[rawJson JSONValue];
```

the rawJson contains a valid string, and everything is working perfectly fine in debug builds

Any suggestions?

Thanx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the reason for this issue:
The project configuration specified the needed linker flags (-ObjC -load_all) for both release and debug, but the target itself only had the needed linker flags for debug. 
After adding the linker flags to the target's release, everything works again.